# Как принудительно открыть autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Использую [Quasar Framework](https://quasar-framework.org/), конкретно проблема с компонентом [Autocomplete](https://quasar-framework.org/components/autocomplete.html):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      query: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    search(val, done) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        return done([{
            label: 'Вариант 1',
            value: 'Вариант 1'
          },
          {
            label: 'Вариант 2',
            value: 'Вариант 2'
          },
          {
            label: 'Вариант 3',
            value: 'Вариант 3'
          }
        ]);
      }, 1000);
    },
    selected(item) {
      this.query = (item) ? item.value : '';
    },
    clickHandler() {
      this.query = 'Тест';

      this.search(this.query, (items) => {
        // как заставить q-autocomplete искать "Тест"?
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ionicons@^4.0.0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@^2.0.0/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@^3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar-framework@0.17.8/dist/umd/quasar.mat.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="app">
    <q-search v-model="query" placeholder="Поиск">
      <q-autocomplete @search="search" @selected="selected" />
    </q-search>
    <p>Модель: {{ query }}</p>
    <q-btn @click="clickHandler">Вставить слово "Тест" и начать поиск</q-btn> - как заставить её работать?
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar-framework@0.17.8/dist/umd/quasar.ie.polyfills.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar-framework@0.17.8/dist/umd/quasar.mat.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar-framework@0.17.8/dist/umd/i18n.pt-br.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar-framework@0.17.8/dist/umd/icons.fontawesome.umd.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Если начать вводить текст в поле "Поиск" - через секунду выдаст 3 результата. Но мне нужно сделать так, чтобы я не вводил "ручками" текст, а нажал на кнопку и он подставился в поле "Поиск" и начал искать эти же 3 варианта. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что проблема в реактивности параметра `items`. Я не нашел, где он у Вас применяется, однако думаю, что если Вы поставите наблюдатель за ним (через сomputed), то все должно заработать. Примерно так:

```
computed:{
  newItems(){
    return this.items
  }
}
```

В коллбеке `search`, сделайте присвоение `this.items = items`

Comment: items не обязательно должен быть реактивным... он нам нужен для выдачи списка (который по какой-то причине не хочет открываться при изменении query). я его вообще удалил и без него тоже работает с вводом))

Answer (score 0):

Временно удалось решить проблему добавив это:

```
const autocomplete = this.$refs.autocomplete;

autocomplete.results = this.items;
autocomplete.__showResults();
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      items: [],
      query: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    search(val, done = null) {
      this.items = [{
          label: 'Вариант 1',
          value: 'Вариант 1'
        },
        {
          label: 'Вариант 2',
          value: 'Вариант 2'
        },
        {
          label: 'Вариант 3',
          value: 'Вариант 3'
        }
      ];

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (done) done(this.items);
        else {
          const autocomplete = this.$refs.autocomplete;
          
          console.log(autocomplete);

          autocomplete.results = this.items;
          autocomplete.__showResults();
        }
      }, 1000);
    },
    selected(item) {
      this.query = (item) ? item.value : '';
    },
    clickHandler() {
      this.query = 'Тест';

      this.search(this.query);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ionicons@^4.0.0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@^2.0.0/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@^3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar-framework@0.17.8/dist/umd/quasar.mat.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="app">
    <q-search v-model="query" placeholder="Поиск">
      <q-autocomplete @search="search" @selected="selected" ref="autocomplete" />
    </q-search>
    <p>Модель: {{ query }}</p>
    <q-btn @click="clickHandler">Вставить слово "Тест" и начать поиск</q-btn> - как заставить её работать?
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar-framework@0.17.8/dist/umd/quasar.ie.polyfills.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar-framework@0.17.8/dist/umd/quasar.mat.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar-framework@0.17.8/dist/umd/i18n.pt-br.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar-framework@0.17.8/dist/umd/icons.fontawesome.umd.min.js"></script>
</body>
```